# Liquid Image Transition Effect Multiple Images

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap

I'm trying to achieve a liquid transition effect when my images change as I hover over different list items. I'm using GSAP, three.js and Robin Dela's hover-effect. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.Here is my Javascript code. Can some one point out where I may be going wrong?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".main-menu a");
    var subMenuImages = document.querySelector(".sub-menu-images");
    var defaultList = document.getElementById("women-list"); 

    // Initialize the hover effect
    var hoverEffect = new hoverEffect({
        parent: subMenuImages,
        intensity: 0.2,
        image1: "/assets/images/braids.jpg", // Default image
        image2: "", 
        displacementImage: "/assets/images/distort.png"
    });

    menuLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var target = this.getAttribute("href");
            var targetList = document.querySelector(target);

            var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu-links");
            lists.forEach(function(list) {
                list.style.display = "none";
            });

            var defaultLink = document.querySelector(".main-menu .active-link");
            if (defaultLink) {
                defaultLink.classList.remove("active-link");
            }

            this.classList.add("active-link");

            targetList.style.display = "block";

            var listItems = targetList.querySelectorAll("li");
            listItems.forEach(function(item, index) {
                item.style.animationDelay = (index * 0.3) + "s";
            });

            // Update the hover effect image on menu item click
            var firstItem = targetList.querySelector("li:first-child");
            var imageURL = firstItem.getAttribute("data-image");
            hoverEffect.next(imageURL);
        });
    });

    var subMenuLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu-links li");

    subMenuLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            var imageURL = this.getAttribute("data-image");
            hoverEffect.next(imageURL);
        });
    });

    // Set default image on page load
    var defaultImageURL = defaultList.querySelector("li:first-child").getAttribute("data-image");
    hoverEffect.next(defaultImageURL);
});
```